# ASP.NET Core 5 application cannot find view error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

I've created an ASP.NET Core 5 application project in Visual Studio 2019.

The requirement is that the views should not be precompiled.

So I set the RazorCompileOnPublish to false:

```
<RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>
```

in the `.csproj` file.

After publishing the project, the `Views` folder was copied to the published directory.

But at runtime, I got the following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> ```
>   /Views/Home/Index.cshtml  
>   /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
> ```
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[9] *

The program.cs and Startup.cs files are as follows:

```
public class Startup
{        
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }     

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();           
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }          
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //endpoints.MapRazorPages(); //Has no effect
        });
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine($"ContentRoot set to: {Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}");
        var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                webBuilder.UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())                    
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
        return hostBuilder;
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This setting can be used in .net core 2.x, but cannot enable runtime compilation in .net core 5.

1. In this case, you can use `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation` to enable runtime compilation.

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    }
   ```
2. The another way is to enable runtime compilation conditionally.

   ```
   public Startup(IConfiguration configuration,IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        Env = webHostEnvironment;
    }
    //...
    public IWebHostEnvironment Env { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IMvcBuilder builder = services.AddRazorPages();

        if (!Env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        }
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
   ```

And you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-in-an-existing-project).

I edit `Index.cshtml` in editor.

[image]

Then save it in publish folder and start the project. It compiled as this.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Karney, I don't want the View files to be compiled to the dll. I want to edit the .cshtml post publishing the web application.

Comment: Yes, you can edit `.cshtml`, then put it in the view folder, the view will be changed.